# How to get higher accuracy with tensorflow CNN.

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have created a CNN for classifing images of weeds. The images are 128*128 and I am getting horrible accuracy. Between 18-32%, where I have four classes. Three of them are different types of weed and the last is no weed. Total there is around 1000 images. What am I doing so wrong that my accuracy is this horrible (sometimes worse than guessing). Are my images scaled down to much? (Originally 425*425), are my layers wrong? Are there too little images to train on?
And is there any way I can with my current setup improve the results? I am currently new to tensorflow so this is not necessarily optimal. The code are partly from tutorials modified to suit my needs.

My code looks like this:

## Helper functions:

```
def parse_function(filename, label):
    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(image_string, channels=3)
    #image_resized = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image, 128, 128)
    new_image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image, 128,128)

    return new_image, label



# INIT weights
def init_weights(shape):
    init_random_dist = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return (tf.Variable(init_random_dist))


# INIT Bias
def init_bias(shape):
    init_bias_vals = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(init_bias_vals)


# CONV2D
def conv2d(x, W):
    # x --> input tensor [batch, H, W, Channels]
    # W --> [filter H, filter W, Channels IN, Channels OUT]
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


# Pooling
def max_pooling_2by2(x):
    # x --> [batch, h, w, c]
    return tf.nn.max_pool(
        x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


#Convolutional layer
def convolutional_layer(input_x, shape):
    W = init_weights(shape)
    b = init_bias([shape[3]])

    return tf.nn.relu(conv2d(input_x, W) + b)


# Normal (FULLY CONNTCTED)
def normal_full_layer(input_layer, size):
    input_size = int(input_layer.get_shape()[1])
    W = init_weights([input_size, size])
    b = init_bias([size])
    return tf.matmul(input_layer, W) + b
```

## My main class

```
def main():
    one_hot_encoded_labels_dummy = []
    one_hot_encoded_test_labels_dummy = []
    filenames_dummy, labels_dummy, test_filenames_dummy,    test_labels_dummy = image_util.run_it()

    for x in labels_dummy:
        one_hot_encoded_labels_dummy.append(wd.one_hot_encoder(x))

    for y in test_labels_dummy:
        one_hot_encoded_test_labels_dummy.append(wd.one_hot_encoder(y))

    filenames = tf.constant(filenames_dummy)
    labels = tf.constant(one_hot_encoded_labels_dummy)
    test_filenames = tf.constant(test_filenames_dummy)
    test_lables = tf.constant(one_hot_encoded_test_labels_dummy)

    dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
    dataset = dataset.map(wd.parse_function)

    test_dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_filenames,
                                                           test_lables))
    test_dataset = test_dataset.map(wd.parse_function)

    dataset = dataset.batch(5)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(filenames_dummy))
    dataset = dataset.repeat()

    test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(60)
    test_dataset = test_dataset.repeat()

    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    test_iterator = test_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

    # PLACEHOLDERS
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 128, 128, 3])
    y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 4])

    convo_1 = wd.convolutional_layer(x, shape=[5,5,3,128])
    convo_1_pooling = wd.max_pooling_2by2(convo_1)

    convo_2 = wd.convolutional_layer(convo_1_pooling, shape=[5,5,128, 128*2])
    convo_2_pooling = wd.max_pooling_2by2(convo_2)

    convo_2_flat = tf.reshape(convo_2_pooling, [-1,32*32*256])

    full_layer_one = tf.nn.relu(wd.normal_full_layer(convo_2_flat, 1024))

    # Dropout
    hold_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    full_one_dropout = tf.nn.dropout(full_layer_one, keep_prob=hold_prob)

    y_pred = wd.normal_full_layer(full_one_dropout, 4)

    # LOSS function
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=y_pred))

    # Optimizer
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001).minimize(cross_entropy)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    steps = 1000

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)

        for i in range(steps):

            value_x, value_y = iterator.get_next()
            batch_x, batch_y = sess.run([value_x, value_y])

            cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=y_pred))

            _, loss_val = sess.run([
                optimizer, cross_entropy], feed_dict={
                    x: batch_x,
                    y_true: batch_y,
                    hold_prob: 0.5
                })

            print(loss_val, " is the loss")

            if i % 10 == 0:
                print("ON STEP {}".format(i))
                print("Accuracy: ")
                matches = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pred, 1), tf.argmax(y_true, 1))
                accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(matches, tf.float32))

                test_1, test_2 = test_iterator.get_next()
                test_batch_x, test_batch_y = sess.run([test_1, test_2])
                print(sess.run(
                    accuracy,
                    feed_dict={
                        x: test_batch_x,
                        y_true: test_batch_y,
                        hold_prob: 1.0
                    }))

main()
```

Comment: 1000 images seems pretty small to apply CNN on.

Comment: Is it not possible to get some results from it? How many should be the minimum?

Comment: The very first question to ask yourself: are you underfitting or overfitting?

Comment: If your datas evenly balanced you would have 250 images per class. Thats not really much, try with weed and not weed and see if you get some better results, may tell you that you need more images for four classes. Try some image augmentation as well

Comment: stackoverflowuser2010: I guess I am underfitting, because my loss is massive, and with so few data I belive this is part of my problem?

I will try that @djk47463, thank you!

Comment: @EinarJohnsen: You need to put the @ sign in front of other people's user names or else they won't get alert.

Comment: @EinarJohnsen: Generally speaking, you determine if you're underfitting or overfitting by checking the learning curves. But given the fact that you have so little data, it's very likely you're underfitting. Given that you're underfitting, how can you modify a NN to add more learning capacity? Also, did you check the official TensorFlow tutorial and look at the MNIST example?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010
Yes I have looked at the official MNIST example. And most likely I am underfitting. It did not help trying to classify weed vs no weed, I have to little no-weed examples. I also tried only classifying what type of weed, but with these layers this is giving me a average of 32%, which is basically guessing. So I guess i have to either use a standard NN, or create more images, by changing, flipping and distorting?

Comment: @EinarJohnsen: Did you try adding anotther layer, increasing the size of the layers, using a different weight initializer, training for more epochs, graphing J vs epochs, increasing or decreasing the learning rate, etc.?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010
I tried increasing the epochs, decreased the learning rate, decreased the dropout. I had problems having too large layers. If I scaled it up once more, it resulted in a error where it returned: "Killed: 9", which was most likely due to not enough memory. But would more small layers help?

Comment: @EinarJohnsen: Every data set is different, so there is no universal solution. I encourage you to plot J vs # of epochs and investigate from there.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 Can you specify what you mean by J, please? Thanks!

Comment: @EinarJohnsen: J commonly refers to the loss function's output.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 Does my J or loss_val (as I have it) look correct? It varies very much in same iterations. Suddenly it is 1-10k and suddenly 0.98 and it does not seem to affect my accuracy much? How can this be?

Comment: @EinarJohnsen: Read this: http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010, thank you for the help!

Comment: @EinarJohnsen Why not use one of the pretrained models like  inception, resnet or if you need a lightweight model , mobilenet and then finetune from there. This is a better option.

Comment: @AnandCU I could use a pretrained model, but I am new to tensorflow and CNN and therefore want to learn why my model is not performing well. Also how I could increase the accuracy and understand why, but thank you for the tip.

Comment: @EinarJohnsen Fair enough.. Can you provide more information about the training. How long did you train . Did the loss decrease or go up over time?

Comment: @AnandCU I resized the images to 32x32, so the training takes from about 5-10 minutes on CPU (depending on epochs). Since the images were to big to train in the beginning, im afraid I am loosing to much, so I hoped to increase the accuracy by having less features to train. The loss went down over time (training), but stables on a  point and goes a bit up again.